# Java Selenium findelement is not acknowledging an element that is on the page

Tags: google-chrome, java, selenium

If I use developer tools in Chrome, and paste my By.name statement, the page highlights exactly what I'm trying to view.

Here are two java statements sitting right next to each other:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='firstName']")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='shippingCost']")).click();
```

I put these two next to each other to rule out that the driver was broken somehow at the point in the code that these come from. The first statement does clear the text box referenced, but the second is returning NoSuchElementError. I have also tried using By.name as mentioned above, I'm just chasing down why the second throws an error every time.

The page I'm working with is an EXTJS single page website, so the control is always there.  I want to use the .getText().length() to validate that there is now text in this box.

Any help on why I'm unable to click, or even just reference this control, on a page where I'm able to use my xpath or name selectors to see the control on the page.

---Edit to add these pics of the code relevent to the above xpaths

[Sorry, this is another place that doesnt work, [name='shippingTypeGroundDate']](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuFYs.png)

[This is the shippingcost location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXn29.png)

[And this is the working firstName location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRp0z.png)

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: add pictures till i figure out how to get the html segments.  Thought extraction would be the easy part, haha.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether if there is any duplicate elements in the chosen selector. According to your description name field is working as expected and you are facing issues with the shipping cost field. it is possible that there are duplicate elements in inactive status on the same page with the chosen selector.

you can get number of elements present using below java `code` :

```
List<WebElement> listOfElements =driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@name='shippingCost']")); 
System.out.println("Number of elements:" +listOfElements.size());
```

if above solutions not working, try with javascriptexecutor , it will perform these actions even if this element is underneath another element.

Comment: Ok, HTML version, as requested. Working xpath first '<div class="x-form-item " tabindex="-1" id="ext-gen156"><label for="ext-comp-1258" style="width:150px;"
        class="x-form-item-label" id="ext-gen157">First Name:</label>
    <div class="x-form-element" id="x-form-el-ext-comp-1258" style="padding-left:155px"><input type="text" size="20"
            autocomplete="off" id="ext-comp-1258" name="firstName" class=" x-form-text x-form-field"
            style="width: 275px;"></div>
    <div class="x-form-clear-left"></div>
</div>'

Comment: and now the not working xpath segment  '<div id="ext-comp-1293" class=" x-box-item x-box-layout-ct" style="width: 120px; height: 65px; left: 180px; top: 0px;">
    <div class="x-box-inner" id="ext-gen334" style="width: 120px; height: 65px;">
        
    </div>
</div>'     (had to edit from pic for length violations)

Comment: i will try the javascript method (and learn it} as the editor only shows one element when i search by my By string.

Comment: Just tried the search, and received this error, which is the title of this question. `org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException` when it tried to find the control that exists on the page.  It isnt hidden by anything, and it is there at the start of the page, just does not have any text in it.  When i try to check for the length to be greater than zero, I'm getting the above exception.  I' ll  report back if the javascript execute gets around the not being found on the dom issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add explicit wait for the input textbox to be loaded. Then try to click the textbox with Javascript executor. Sometimes webdriver click may not work.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='shippingCost']"));
try {
        if (element.isEnabled() && element.isDisplayed()) {

                ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Unable to click on element");
            }
        } catch (StaleElementReferenceException e) {
            System.out.println("Element is not attached to the page document "+ e.getStackTrace());
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println("Element was not found in DOM "+ e.getStackTrace());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to click on element "+ e.getStackTrace());
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for this example.  My original problem will not let me get past line one.  The problem is the element is not being found.  Forget all the rest we can do once an element becomes found, these paths for shipingCost and shippingTypeGroundDate just will provide NoSuchElementException errors when the code sees them.